# Error: Sequelize Assosication called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hi everyone I'm having an error "**Error: Text.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model**" when I add association of Sequelize in my model it called an error that what I call is not Sequelize Model.

Here is the code of my models, I try to create an association between Post model and Text model.

./Post.js

```js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../db/sequelize.setup');

const Text = require('./Text');

const Post = sequelize.define(
  'Post',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    tags: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    items: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    author: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  },
  {
    modelName: 'Post',
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

  Post.hasMany(Text, {
    as: 'Text',
    foreignKey: 'post_id',
    sourceKey: 'id',
  });

module.exports = Post;
```

./Text.js

```
 const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize = require('../../db/sequelize.setup');
    
    const Post = require('./Post');
    
    const Text = sequelize.define(
      'Text',
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        text: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(),
          allowNull: false,
        },
      },
      {
        modelName: 'Text',
        timestamps: true,
      }
    );
    
    Text.belongsTo(Post, { as: 'Post', foreignKey: 'post_id', targetKey: 'id' });
    
    module.exports = Text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make an *index.js* file in your models folder and inside of it make your association like this

```
const db = {};
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.posts=require("./post.js")(sequlize,sequlize);
db.texts=require....
db.posts.hasMany(db.texts, { foreignKey: 'postId' });
db.texts.belongsTo(db.posts, { foreignKey: 'postId' });
```

and put the postId in text.js model